# objective-c - using a boolean value from one class in another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, boolean

I've looked around and couldn't find a distinct answer to this question. So I'm asking here. I have two classes. ClassA and ClassB. I have a bool value in ClassB. I have a method in ClassA where it is looking for that value in ClassB to be True in order for the method to fire off. I'm not really sure how to get ClassA to see that value. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need the method of Class A to fire as soon as the value in Class B changes? If so, I would look at the observer pattern.

Comment: You obviously mean that you have two instances of these classes right? Because Classes do not hold any data themselves, they are just "blueprints" of objects instantiated from these...

Comment: Maybe. I have a button in ClassA when clicked fires off the method in ClassB, which has an if/else statement in it, that is looking for the bool value to be true/false. I got the method to fire, but it is always saying that the bool=false, when it is set to true in the other class

Comment: whats your problem in defining a boolean property in class B and make if statement to check it ?!! or use NSUserDefaults to store it ?

Comment: @donutdude246 - your comment says your code always finds the value to be false, so you are trying somehow to access it. Add to your question the definition of the bool in class A, the class A call to the method in class B, and the class B method showing the attempted access. With those details somebody might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be careful with the "global definition".
if your class must save the user settings, you can use:
for save:

```
 NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [pref setBool:YES forKey:@"AudioIsON"];
 [pref synchronize];
```

for reading:

```
BOOL myBooleanSetting = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AudioIsON"];
```

instead of, is better to learn the delegate and the property.

hope this help you.