# Saving and Loading settings by NSUserDefault on UIswitches Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiswitch

I have a settings view where i have provided the option for users to change their settings.

Settings view have a `table view` having 2 `UISwitches`. I need help with `NSUserdefaults` method for saving states, and how I can write the code to load my values.

Here is my code so far

```
In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

      [cell.switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"myBool"];
    BOOL hBool = [[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"myBool"];

    NSLog(@"tag %i", tappedSwitch.tag);

    if (cell.switchButton.tag == 0) {
        [cell.switchButton setOn:hBool];

    }    
return cell;
}



    - (void) switchButtonTapped: (id) sender {

            tappedSwitch = (UISwitch *) sender;
        switch (tappedSwitch.tag) {
            case 0:
                passcodeSwitchIsOn = tappedSwitch.isOn;
                if (passcodeSwitchIsOn) {

                    GCPINViewController *PIN = [[GCPINViewController alloc]
                                                initWithNibName:nil
                                                bundle:nil
                                                mode:GCPINViewControllerModeCreate];
                    PIN.messageText = @"Enter a passcode";
                    PIN.errorText = @"The passcodes do not match";
                    PIN.title = @"Set Passcode";
                    PIN.verifyBlock = ^(NSString *code) {
                    NSLog(@"setting code: %@", code);
                    code = saveString; 
                    return YES;
                        };
                    [PIN presentFromViewController:self animated:YES];
                    [PIN release];
     // method of saving                    
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
                [defaults setBool:passcodeSwitchIsOn forKey:@"myBool"];
                [defaults synchronize];
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                bluetoothSwitchIsOn = tappedSwitch.isOn;
                if (bluetoothSwitchIsOn) {

                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bluetooth Switch" message:@"Bluetooth Switch is ON" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];

                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
            [settingsTable reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isSwitchOn"]` use this as per switch states

Comment: go to look [this][1] maybe help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828868/objective-c-using-a-boolean-value-from-one-class-in-another-class/9830139#9830139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This can be used for handling your issue.**

```
IBOutlet UISwitch * swi_yourswitch;
@property(nonatomic,retain)  UISwitch * swi_yourswitch;
```

**implimentation**

```
@synthesise swi_yourswitch;

- (void) switchButtonTapped: (id) sender {
    UISwitch * switchObj = (UISwitch*)sender;
    if(switchObj == self.swi_yourswitch){
        if (self.swi_yourswitch.on){

            NSLog(@"On");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Off");
            [self.swi_yourswitch setOn:0];
        }
    }
```

**To store value**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"mybool"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**To get stored value**

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"mybool"]
```

Comment: Whats swi_yourswitch? And valueForKey is used for NSString I guess.

Comment: swi_yourswitch is a uiswitch instance .You can check whether your switch is clicked.Also you can declare any number of switches in setting page.

Comment: And to get stored string value we use value for key..Hope you understand this.

Answer (score 3):

Create a reference to your user defaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Set a value:

```
[defaults setBool:1 forKey:@"bluetooth"];
```

You can set this back to 0 when bluetooth is off:

```
[defaults setBool:0 forKey:@"bluetooth"];
```

The user default is identified by the string of your choice. In this case: @"bluetooth". The value for the default will be nil until you create it and set it to something else.

So you can say:

```
if (!bluetooth) // bluetooth is off
else  // bluetooth is on
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html